# Python: String Formatter Align center

Tags: python, string-formatting, text-alignment

```
print('%24s' % "MyString")     # prints right aligned
print('%-24s' % "MyString")    # prints left aligned
```

How do I print it in the center? Is there a quick way to do this?

I don't want the text to be in the center of my screen. I want it to be in the center of *that* 24 spaces. If I have to do it manually, what is the math behind adding the same no. of spaces before and after the text?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use the new-style `format` method instead of the old-style `%` operator, which doesn't have the centering functionality:

```
print('{:^24s}'.format("MyString"))
```

Comment: Oh wow, this should be helpful for all python newbies like me; I wouldn't have noticed it if I started all the way without asking this question

Comment: This method reduces the space the longer the string, until the point where there is no space.

Comment: print(f'{"MyString":^24s}')

Comment: What does the s at the end do?

Comment: s stands for string - there are also other format specifications like d for decimals, f for fixed-point floats etc., see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Answer (score 39):

You can use [`str.center()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) method.

In your case, it will be: `"MyString".center(24)`

Comment: Imho better than format options because clearly expresses the intent, not only that but also one can use a fill character different from the default `" "` , as  can be shown in the following example: `print("MyString".center(24, "-")` → `--------MyString--------`

Comment: @gboffi changing the fill character is possible with `format` too: `print('{:#^24s},'.format("MyString"))`

Comment: this method allows us to use it with old formatting style `print('%24s' % "MyString".center(24))`

Answer (score 10):

> Python 3:

You can follow the below syntax:

```
stringName.center(width,fillChar)
```

In your example:

```
"MyString".center(24," ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would use .format().

Resource that explains center. along with others [here](https://pyformat.info/)