# How to remove parenthesis and comma from output (and tell me what I did wrong)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have an assignment about class in python. I've done almost the same as the desired output. But mine prints with parenthesis and comma and in a tuple (I don't even know how its in a tuple). Nowhere do I specify it to be tuple. What did I do wrong?

```
class buttons:
    def __init__(self,word,spaces,border):
        self.word = word
        self.spaces = spaces
        self.border = border

word = "CANCEL"
spaces = 10
border = 'x'
b1 = buttons(word, spaces, border)
print('CANCEL Button Specification:')
print('Button Name:', b1.word)
b1_bord = 1+b1.spaces+len(b1.word)+b1.spaces+1
print('Number of the border characters for the top and the bottom:', b1_bord)
print('Number of spaces between the left side border and the first character of the button \nname:', b1.spaces)
print('Number of spaces between the right side border and the last character of the button \nname:', b1.spaces)
print('Characters representing the borders:', b1.border)
emp = ''
print(b1.border*b1_bord)
print(f'{b1.border,(emp*spaces),b1.word,(emp*b1.spaces),b1.border}')
print(b1.border*b1_bord)
print("=======================================================")
b2 = buttons("Notify",3, '!')
print('NOTIFY Button Specification:')
print('Button Name:', b2.word)
b2_bord = 1+b2.spaces+len(b2.word)+b2.spaces+1
print('Number of the border characters for the top and the bottom:', b2_bord)
print('Number of spaces between the left side border and the first character of the button \nname:', b2.spaces)
print('Number of spaces between the right side border and the last character of the button \nname:', b2.spaces)
print('Characters representing the borders:', b2.border)
print(b2.border*b2_bord)
print(f'{b2.border,(emp*b2.spaces),b2.word,(emp*b2.spaces),b2.border}')
print(b2.border*b2_bord)
print("=======================================================")
b3 = buttons('SAVE PROGRESS', 5, '$')
print('SAVE PROGRESS Button Specification:')
print('Button Name:', b3.word)
b3_bord = 1+b3.spaces+len(b3.word)+b3.spaces+1
print('Number of the border characters for the top and the bottom:', b3_bord)
print('Number of spaces between the left side border and the first character of the button \nname:', b3.spaces)
print('Number of spaces between the right side border and the last character of the button \nname:', b3.spaces)
print('Characters representing the borders:', b3.border)
print(b3.border*b3_bord)
print(f'{b3.border,(emp*b3.spaces),b3.word,(emp*b3.spaces),b3.border}')
print(b3.border*b3_bord)
```

The output I get:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
('x', '', 'CANCEL', '', 'x')
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
('!', '', 'Notify', '', '!')
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
('$', '', 'SAVE PROGRESS', '', '$')
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

The output I need:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x         CANCEL           x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!   Notify   !
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$     SAVE PROGRESS     $
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

Comment: `print(f'{b3.border,(emp*b3.spaces),b3.word,(emp*b3.spaces),b3.border}')` -- There you are telling it to print a tuple. Why are you using an f-string here and in other places not?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44781576/2681662

Comment: @MSH Not really. I need to make print word variable between spaces variable

Comment: Ok removing the format button removed the tuple and the parenthesis and comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```py
def make_btn(word, space, border):
    middle = border + word.center(space*2+len(word)) + border 
    edge = border*len(middle)
    return f'{edge}\n{middle}\n{edge}'

print(make_btn('CANCEL',10,'x'))
print(make_btn('Notify',3,'!'))
print(make_btn('SAVE PROGRESS',5,'$'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

```
emp = ''
```

should be:

```
emp = ' '
```

And secondly,

```
print(f'{b1.border(emp*b1.spaces),b1.word(emp*b1.spaces),b1.border}')
```

should be:

```
print(b1.border+(emp*spaces)+b1.word+(emp*b1.spaces)+b1.border)
```

> You are using [Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) with `printf` which is unnecessary in this case. Just use `print`. And also, use '+' instead of ',' to join strings.

Repeat the `print` statement for `b2` and `b3`.